# What would I need to adjust to make a Medium Glass Golem?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, constructs

Craft Construct allows a PC to build a construct, allowing a 10th level crafty-type wizard to make a Large Glass Golem using reasonably simple rules.

In the options, and for a clearly understood additional cost, a crafty type wizard can make his construct work as armor, which rules are also clear. They also clearly state that the construct must be the same size as the creator. I might house rule away the 'creator' bit so the party can have Guyver-golems, but I digress.

If I were to rule that a Medium Glass golem were craftable, and anticipating that I would NOT make the thing any cheaper to actually build for balance reasons, what should I actually adjust?

The normal things spring to mind. It should probably lose strength and hit points (as it will be missing some construct size bonus hp), and I could reasonably give it back some dexterity.
What am I missing?

For that matter, does anyone have a lesser glass golem of fluff text +1 laying around I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial response is to keep the Glass Golem Large and let the wearer use it like heavy powered armor.  If you think about it, Guyver was taller in the armor.  However, that doesn't answer your question so....

According to [Pathfinder Construct Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs/) (that you've obviously read), there is nothing in the "New Construct" section that talks about size.  They base the price on CR.

So the simplest answer is to use the Monster Template:  [Simple, Young](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/simple-template-young-cr-1/).  That gives a -1 CR and you can adjust your price using that.  I don't really like the way that works out though.  It seems pretty pathetic to me.

So, I would say that the cost remains the same.  You might use less material but it has to be made with finer detail.  Then adjust the stats in the standard way for reducing size (STR, DEX, AC, etc.).

If you want to reduce the cost, then you should probably reduce the Natural Armor as you are getting cost savings by thinning it out.

In case you haven't seen it, there is also:  [Transforming Construct](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/transforming-construct-cr-1/).   Robotech anyone?

Comment: I also have considered allowing the Large golems to be armor as is. Not quite sure how to properly balance it. It essentially becomes half or full plate with enlarge person and damage reduction, but to price it I'll have to shop around for similar effects.

Answer (score 0):

When you change a creature's size, you apply adjustments from this table: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-advancement/
For dropping from Large to Medium, it looks like you'd apply -8 STR, -4 CON, +2 DEX, -3 natural armor. You might also decrease hit dice -- I think with animals the rule is that a size change doubles or halves the hit dice, though I don't have a strong citation for that. The decreased hit dice would mean recalculating saves and attacks as well.

Comment: On your second point, that may not be a fair comparison; the golem acts as a Breastplate AC-wise, but gives you an additional pool of health equal to the golem

Comment: Good catch. Removed.